# Google Web Fonts encoding/rendering issue

Tags: html, character-encoding, webfonts, google-webfonts

I am trying to solve an issue with Google WebFonts. I want to use font [Signika](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Signika) from them. As you can see it has letters such as Š, Ů declared/implemented. On our [website](http://idband.collin.sk), however, it does not render these letters but just standard and in word **DOMŮ** - letter **Ů** is in another font and in word **DALŠI** letter **Š** in another font. Is there any solution for this? Should I declare some encoding for these types of letters, or where could the problem be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When i look at your website, i see both the words (and individual letters) you list as problematic in the font Signika.

I do notice however, that you are only calling for the Standard font set, and not the Laten-Extended Subset. On [this page](http://www.google.com/webfonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Signika) you may want to check the box `Latin Extended (latin-ext)` and update your code if other browsers are experiencing problems.

Comment: The problematic letters appear in the browser’s default sans-serif font, since the selected version of Signika does not contain them and the CSS rule `font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif` is applied. However, if the visitor’s computer has a font named Signika installed locally, then that font is used (but most visitors haven’t got it of course). The suggested solution is correct. You can also take the shortcut of appending `&subset=latin,latin-ext` to the `href` value in the `link` element that refers to the Google service.

Comment: Thank you ! It works I didnt noticed the button latin-extended so now its working perfect ! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If characters are implemented in the font file but your site can not display it you need to check if you are calling right subsets:

For example, to request the latin and latin-endended subsets of Oswald, the URL would be:

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald&subset=latin,latin-ext
```

For more information:

https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started#Subsets

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I was having this problem even with the same font name.